# Sqlite Unhandled Exception xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to learn basic insert function.When I start clicked button I Received unhandled exception.I think my Path folder is right.I don't know what mistake that i make.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

[image]

**NewTravelPage.xaml.cs**

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TravelRecordApp.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TravelRecordApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewTravelPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewTravelPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        public void ToolBarItem_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                Experience = experienceEntry.Text
            };

            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
            connection.CreateTable<Post>();

            int rows = connection.Insert(post);

            connection.Close();

            if (rows > 0)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Success", "Experience successfully inserted", "OK!");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Failed", "Experience failed to inserted", "ok!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs (Android folder)**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;

namespace TravelRecordApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TravelRecordApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            string fileName = "travel_db.sqlite";
            string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

            LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug and check what is the value of  `App.DatabaseLocation`?

Comment: What does the error message say? Is it true?

Comment: @Sunil "/data/data/com.companyname.TravelRecordApp/files/travel_db.sqlite"

Comment: @PatrickHofman where can i get the error message?

Comment: In your screenshot of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteConnection` requires `connectionString` and not just path to your database.

You are passing:

```
/data/data/com.companyname.TravelRecordApp/files/travel_db.sqlite
```

You are **expected** to pass:

```
Data Source=/data/data/com.companyname.TravelRecordApp/files/travel_db.sqlite
```

Try this line:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=/data/data/com.companyname.TravelRecordApp/files/travel_db.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 0):

when passing the DB path you need to pass the connection string properly (and not only path to DB file).

For example:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\PATH_TO_DB\db.sqlite;");
```